# Is it correct to use "should have" in the following situation?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

I made up the situation:

A and B are boxers. A is superior to B. A fought B, A lost. A must have been jet-lagged so A lost. 
If everything was ok, A would have won.

Would it be correct to say: A should have won?

Comment: There is little to choose between them: **would have** states a fact - how things would have turned out in other circumstances. **Should have** states an expectation of the likely result..

Comment: Let's say I rooted for B, I wanted B to win. But I knew that B was likely to lose. Does it make sense to say "I am very pleased that B won, though B shouldn't have won"?

Comment: @RonaldSole: ***OR*** - we might sayu that ***should have*** states an expectation of the ***preferable*** or ***more fitting*** result, even if that particular outcome might actually be less likely than others. (Children ***should*** be seen and not heard, but that's not usually what happens!  :)

Comment: Could anyone answer my initial question and the one in my above comment, please? Just yes or no. I need nothing more, as I've learned enough about "should". I'm just not sure if it is correct to use "should" in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

> A would have won.

*Would have* is the part of the third conditional, but it can be used without an 'if clause'. It means it was possible for A to win, but A didn't win.

> A should have won.

It means winning of A was a good idea, but A didn't win anyway.